# Quotient stack is an algebraic space when $G$ is finite and acts freely

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks, group-schemes, algebraic-spaces

I have been following Jarod Alper's lecture series on YouTube on Stacks https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLhFI5R_xInjdhtWuhgYlA8NZGXO-unnl4

From what I understand -

1. If a smooth affine group scheme $G$ acts on an algebraic space $X$ then $[X/G]$ is an algebraic stack(i.e there is a smooth presentation which is representable in the weak sense)
2. If $G$ is a finite group acting freely on $X$ then $[X/G]$ is an algebraic space, as opposed to being an algebraic stack (i.e there exists an etale presentation which is representable in the strong sense).

> Assuming statement 1, how can I prove statement 2?

> If I weaken the conditions on $G$ what can I say about $[X/G]$?

[Here weak and strong representability means representable by algebraic space and scheme respectively]

Comment: To prove 2, you could use the following fact: An algebraic stack is an algebraic space if and only if its (geometric) inertia groups are all trivial. Now, if $G$ acts freely on $X$, then all stabilizers of the $G$-action are (by definition) trivial.  On the other hand, the stabilizers correspond to the inertia groups of $[X/G]$. Thus, those are trivial.

Comment: I just noticed that the title does not reflect the question in the post correctly. I would suggest "Quotient stack is an algebraic space when $G$ is finite and acts freely"

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar  Thank you for your response. I was unaware of the iff condition. Perhaps Prof Alper would mention it in the next few videos which I haven't seen yet.